# A non-convex QCQP

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I have a symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix $M$. Is it possible to solve the following problem as a quadratic problem?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & w^T M w\\ \text{subject to} & w^T w \le 1\\ & A w \ge 0\end{array}$$

where $A$ is some matrix. If not, what is the right tool (maybe even software) to solve this kind of problem? We know also that $w^T M w$ is bounded above by some number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-convex problem (as you are **maximizing** a convex function), so it may be difficult.  Cplex should be able to do it, though, if the number of variables is not too big.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hard problem, both of your constraints (the sphere and the linear plane) are differentiable and convex. You can use the "fmincon" function of MATLAB. Remember to use the negative of the objective since fmincon minimizes by default

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a special case of the extended CDT subproblem. You can check whether you can obtain its solution using its dual problem's solution by checking the necessary and sufficient conditions for strong duality in your case.

Here is a paper for your reference:

[Strong Duality for the CDT Subproblem: A Necessary and Sufficient Condition](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/07070601X?journalCode=sjope8)